# Set one of two Angular Material select to required based on a condition

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a simple form which operates on the logic of:

Select Box 1 (Yes/No)

Select Box 2 (Show if Yes)
Select Box 3 (Show if No)

Only the shown selection box should be set to required, the other is not required.

```
<mat-select placeholder='Show First Options' formControlName='b' [(ngModel)]="view">
    <mat-option [value]="'first'">
       First
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option  [value]="'second'">
      Second
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field> 

<mat-form-field *ngIf="view === 'first'">
  <mat-select       
      placeholder='First Items' 
      formControlName='one'
      [required]="view === 'first'">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items1" [value]="item">
      {{item}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field *ngIf="view === 'second'">
  <mat-select
      placeholder='Second Items'
      formControlName='two'
      [required]="view === 'second'"> 
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items2" [value]="item">
      {{item}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

This works fine for the first, default select box. However, when you change to the second box, the first box seems to keep its required validator.

I have written a demo to demonstrate this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9eoffq

How can I ensure only the viewed select box is required?

Comment: I'm must be misunderstanding your issue, because I can't reproduce it on the demo. Can you explain in a step by step example what your issue is?

Comment: as @FredrikLundin said your problem is not reproductible in demo , can you explain more ?

Comment: Sorry guys - you may have had that issue because I was continuously working against the demo which in hindsight was a dumb idea from me. However I did manage to fix it; I attached an answer to this question in case anyone else has this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for editing the demo provided as people were reviewing it which caused confusion, however I seemed to have solved it - the issue seemed to stem from the DOM re-rendering to remove the `mat-form-field` before removing the `required` tag. This meant that the form still had the required attribute.

The demo has been updated with the solution - I had to programatically remove the required validator and add it to the appropriate form control. Then I had to update the value and validity to clear the errors after the validators were changed.

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
     if(value.b === 'first') {
         this.form.controls['one'].setValidators(Validators.required)
         this.form.controls['two'].clearValidators()
     } else {
         this.form.controls['two'].setValidators(Validators.required)
         this.form.controls['one'].clearValidators()
     }    

     this.form.controls['one'].updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf:true})
     this.form.controls['two'].updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf:true})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ngModel` you can instead make full use of your reactive form, and utilize the form controls. Also, by disabling and enabling fields they are either included/excluded from the form object, therefore also validations will not apply.

You could listen to `valueChanges` of form, but I like to avoid it since if you are having a large form, it will be fired excessively. But if you want to only listen to a specific control changes, you can also do that. I like a simple `change` event here though:

```
<mat-select formControlName='b' (change)="onChange()">
```

and then hiding/showing the other select:

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="form.controls.b.value === 'first'">
<!-- -->
<mat-form-field *ngIf="form.controls.b.value === 'second'">
```

and the change event:

```
onChange() {
  if(this.form.get('b').value === 'first') {
    this.form.get('one').enable()
    this.form.get('two').disable()
  } else {
    this.form.get('one').disable()
    this.form.get('two').enable()     
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l7ad2w?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

With this, we need to remember that the disabled control(s) are excluded from the form object, if you want all values (disabled included), you need to call `this.form.getRawValue()`

Answer (score 0):

Still some one is looking for another solution, this may help.

```
<mat-select placeholder='Show First Options' formControlName='b' [(ngModel)]="view" #optionsSelector>
    <mat-option value="first"> First </mat-option>
    <mat-option value="second"> Second </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field> 

<mat-form-field *ngIf="optionsSelector.value === 'first'">
  <mat-select placeholder='First Items' formControlName='one'>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items1" [value]="item">
      {{item}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field *ngIf="optionsSelector.value === 'second'">
  <mat-select placeholder='Second Items'  formControlName='two'> 
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items2" [value]="item">
      {{item}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```